# Methods compiled with typescript and gulp are not callable from my index.html, in a hello world program

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, browserify

I am new to typescript and gulp.
I was setting up a gulp and typescript project for a hello world browser based project.
Here is the git repo for that :
https://github.com/anuragvohraec/typescript-gulp-front-end

Here is how I have structured my project
[image]

Now when I run `gulp` command [gulp file can be seen in the git repo, not added here for brevity].

my bundle.js is created in dist folder.
My Index.html has following structure

[image]

The button is binded like this to the JS method:
`<button onclick="getmessage();">Click me once</button>`

But when I press button it gives me : 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: getmessage is not defined`

I am not able to figure out what I doing wrong, please can some one help me here ?

Note: I use web server for chrome to run the dist folder on local host.

Comment: it seems there is something wrong in gulpfile.js

Comment: @Supercool. I added this lines in index.ts `(<any>window).mp = {};(<any>window).mp.getmessage=getmessage;` and then used it as `window.mp.getmessage()` in my index.thml, it works. This means gulpfile is doing it all good.

Comment: well good!!....Answer to this question so that anyone who has this problem will find solution

Comment: @Supercool. but it doesnot seems the right approach, if I have hundereds of classes which I need to expose in my browser, then its impratical. There must be a solution people are employing for it.